# How to change recyclerview background(not item background) color dynamically based on child position?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview like the image below

[image: this image]

the background color is given dynamically in adapter using position, hence only if there is item(card) i can color the background i have linearlayout as cardview's parent and i am coloring the linear layout.

recyclerview:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        style="@style/scrollbar_style"
        />
```

this is item resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/back"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconEntry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleEntry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleSpanishEntry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countEntry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

adapter:

```
    public LinearLayout back;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        back = view.findViewById(R.id.back);
    }
```

adapter onBindViewHolder:

```
holder.back.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(
EntriesItemList.get(getCategory(position))
.getDisposalTypeCategory()
.getColor()));
```

now the requirement is color even if there is no item like the empty space in 1st section.

that can be done only if i can change the recyclerview background(not card background) dynamically based on adapter position, but looks impossible as there is no relation between the two. any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Rather giving color to individual item of recycler view give background color to that specific recycler view

Comment: thats my question.. how to give color dynamically to recyclerview programatically based on position, it cant be 1 single color

Comment: @SiddarthG how did you load different no of items in each sections?

Comment: its a gridLayoutManager recyclerview and i have used SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter for sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by always making sure there are 3 items in a row by adding dummy invisible items, so that the background color extends all the way through the row.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is that you pass the RecyclerView in the adapter constructor and in your adapter onBindViewHolder method change the RecyclerView background according to your adapter position.

Comment: it will change the whole background i think not just that section?

Comment: Yes , in onBindViewHolder , just change the background of the recyclerView that you passed in  the constructor according to the adapter position

Comment: this is for example your constructor : 
public YourAdapter(List yourList, Context context, View yourRecyclerView) {
        this.yourList= yourList;
        this.context = context;
        this.recyclerView= yourRecyclerView;

    }


then  in onBindViewHolder :

if (yourList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).......)
recyclerView.setBackgroundColor(..);


,

Comment: does not work, it will color the whole list with single color

Comment: try holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor();

Comment: that im already doing hence the items which exists have color